# Inequality for sum of independent random integers

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, inequality, expectation

Let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$ be independent random non-negative integers and let $n>0$ be a positive integer. Does the following hold?
$$
P(Y_1+\cdots +Y_k<n)\geq \prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{EY_i}{n}\right)
$$

---

The case $k=1$ is Markov's inequality. I am actually mostly interested in the case when $k=n$ and the $Y_i$ are iid, although this generalization seemed to be true and might be easier to prove (for instance, by induction on $k$). Of course, it is possible that there is a simple counterexample...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be iid. random variables such that both take the value $2$ with probability $p$ and the value $1$ with probability $1-p$. And let $n=4, \ k=2$.

Then

$$P(Y_1+Y_2<4)=(1-p)^2+2p(1-p)$$

and

$$E[Y_1]=E[Y_2]=2p+(1-p)=1+p.$$

The question is if

$$(1-p)^2+2p(1-p)\ge\left(1-\frac{1+p}4\right)^2$$
for all $p$.

But, no. For $p=\frac9{10}$ the left hand side is less than the right hand side. (The inequality turns upside down at $\sim 0.842$.)